# How do browsers work

Tags: html, browser

I found this excellent article :

[how-browsers-work-part-1-architecture](http://www.vineetgupta.com/2010/11/how-browsers-work-part-1-architecture/)

But i could not find the part 2. I am guessing, once completed, it would explain the following aspects of how a browser works.

```
* Architecture
* HTTP
* Security Model
* Content and Rendering
* JavaScript
* Apps
```

Anyone would like to take a shot at explaining how Content and rendering wise?

also referenced @ [How Browsers Work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

Comment: Holy cow. That article is amazing :)

Comment: This is a related video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA

Comment: The article is on a blog, posted by a user with the name similiar to the domain, and it is being linked to that article stating that’s the original. So there only is a part 1, and the author probably plans or planned on releasing a second part later on. You may want to subscribe to the blog. No dates there sadly …